# How to arrange repeating code in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'ChangeClientId') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE ChangeClientId
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangeClientId] 
    (@dst SYSNAME,
     @NewClientId INT,
     @dryRun BIT = 1)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @TableOfSqls TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Part INT, Sql NVARCHAR(MAX))
    DECLARE @Phase INT = 0
    ...

    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'TRUNCATE TABLE #Failure')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'GO')

    SET @Phase = @Phase + 1

    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, '')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, 'USE [' + @dst + ']')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, 'SET XACT_ABORT ON')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Failure) THROW 50000, ''Skipped due to previous errors'', 0')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'INSERT INTO #Failure VALUES (0)')

    ...
END
```

This code chunk

```
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'TRUNCATE TABLE #Failure')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'GO')

    SET @Phase = @Phase + 1

    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, '')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, 'USE [' + @dst + ']')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, 'SET XACT_ABORT ON')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Failure) THROW 50000, ''Skipped due to previous errors'', 0')
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, 'INSERT INTO #Failure VALUES (0)')
```

repeats several times in the stored procedure. In C# I would have put it in a nested function. In T-SQL I should be able to create a temporary stored procedure or something like that, but I am not sure.

So, my question is - what is the best way to arrange this repeating code to reduce the clutter?

**Rationale**

This stored procedure generates a big dynamic SQL and executes it. However, it supports dry run, where the SQL is displayed but not run. So, the procedure accumulates all the SQL statements into a table and then either outputs it or composes a SQL string and executes it. There is a catch, though, it proceeds in phases. Each phase is separated with the described piece of code which is repeating, but not identical, because the `@Phase` is incremented in the middle.

Comment: One method is to create another stored procedure for that portion of the code.

Comment: Why many individual `INSERT INTO` statements? Why not do them in one statement?

Comment: Also, the above is wide open to injection; never inject an unsantised string into a dynamic statement. Always properly quote your dynamic objects with `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: This is not a production code, so I do not care much, but you are right.

Comment: There is never a reason to *not* care... Never have code with injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Got it. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding a temporary stored procedure inside mine and calling it instead of the repeating chunk.

Here is the code:

```
...
    DECLARE @Phase INT = 0

    SET @Sql = '
    CREATE PROCEDURE #ChangeClientIdSqlHelper(@Phase INT)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TableOfSqls TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Part INT, Sql NVARCHAR(MAX))
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, '''')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, ''TRUNCATE TABLE #Failure'')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, ''GO'')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, '''')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, ''USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dst) + ''')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (@Phase, ''SET XACT_ABORT ON'')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, ''IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Failure) THROW 50000, ''''Skipped due to previous errors'''', 0'')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, ''INSERT INTO #Failure VALUES (0)'')
        INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls VALUES (0, '''')
        SELECT Part, Sql FROM @TableOfSqls ORDER BY Id
    END
    '
    EXEC(@Sql)
...
    SET @Phase = @Phase + 1
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls EXEC #ChangeClientIdSqlHelper @Phase
...
    SET @Phase = @Phase + 1
    INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls EXEC #ChangeClientIdSqlHelper @Phase
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, you can define a second temporary table:

```
DECLARE @Repeats TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Part INT, Sql NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Repeats(Part, SQL) VALUES (@Phase, '')
INSERT INTO @Repeats(Part, SQL) VALUES (@Phase, 'USE [' + @dst + ']')
INSERT INTO @Repeats(Part, SQL) VALUES (@Phase, 'SET XACT_ABORT ON')
INSERT INTO @Repeats(Part, SQL) VALUES (0, 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Failure) THROW 50000, ''Skipped due to previous errors'', 0')
INSERT INTO @Repeats(Part, SQL) VALUES (0, 'INSERT INTO #Failure VALUES (0)')
```

You can then insert this whenever you want:

```
INSERT INTO @TableOfSqls (sql)
    SELECT part, sql
    FROM @Repeats
    ORDER BY id;
```

I'm going to add that breaking out SQL line-by-line seems like a curious approach to writing code.  I'm not 100% sure that dynamic SQL is even necessary.  If it is, you can store an entire block of code (along with the newline characters) in a single string.

Comment: Note there is `SET @Phase = @Phase + 1` in the middle

Comment: Given that the `@Phase` is incremented in each new chunk this proposal does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mark . . . You can increment the `@phase` when you insert the new rows, rather than reading it from the table.

Comment: I am not reading it from a table. `@Phase` is incremented by me in each chunk. But I cannot use the same repeat table, because it would capture the initial `@Phase` value, which is 1.